# Circular Motion: car slipping off a track

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm working on the following problem:

> A car travelling on an unbanked, flat circular track accelerates uniformly from rest with a tangential acceleration of 1.70 $m/s^2$. The car makes it one quarter of the way around the circle before skidding on the track. Find the coefficient of static friction between the car and the track.

I tried setting the centripetal force equal to the force of friction and got this:

$$F_c = F_f$$
$$m\frac{v^2}{R} = \mu m g$$
$$\mu = \frac{v^2}{gR}$$

Then to get $v^2$, I used the equation of circular motion:

$$\omega_f^2 = \omega_i^2 + 2\alpha\theta$$
$$\omega_f^2 = 2\Big(\frac{a}{R}\Big)\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$$
$$\omega_f^2 = \frac{\pi a}{R}$$

Using the relationship that $v = R\omega$, I get:

$$v^2 = \pi aR$$

And finally plugging this back into the equation for $\mu$, I get:

$$\mu = \frac{\pi aR}{gR}$$
$$\mu = \frac{\pi a}{g}$$
$$\mu = \frac{\pi (1.7 m/s^2)}{9.81 m/s^2}$$
$$\mu \approx 0.544$$

However, the solution is $\mu = 0.572$. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: "I tried setting the centripetal force equal to the force of friction" Here is your mistake.  There is not only the centripetal acceleration in this problem but also the tangential one.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint:-Force of friction would have radial as well as tangential component.So,$m\frac{v^2}{R} \neq \mu m g$ Infact $ma_{t}=\mu mg\sin \theta$ and $ma_{r}=\mu mg\cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between force of friction and radial vector(I assume that radial vector is pointing towards the centre)

Comment: Not sure about the trigonometry - everything is at right angles...

Comment: Tangential and radial vectors are perpendicular

Comment: Exactly. So sine and cosine are 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks Shreyansh! I didn't think the tangential friction would contribute to the car slipping off the track but clearly it does. Also, I do agree with Oscar, writing $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ is rather cumbersome for this problem.

Answer (score -2):

@Shreyansh makes a good point about including the accelerating force in the calculation (although I think he goes too far with the trigonometry...).

Everything is at right angles so the net force is:
$$
F_{f} = \sqrt{F_{c}^2 + F_{l}^2}
$$
See where that gets you...

Comment: Downvote? What's wrong? too much? too little?... How can I improve myself?